# Unable to deploy flutter project to Github Pages

Tags: flutter, dart, github, web, github-pages

I can't host flutter web application on github pages. The workflow file looks like this:

```yaml
name: Build & Deploy weathunits_configurator

on:
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  build-and-deploy:
    name: 'Build & Deploy web app'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: 'Install Flutter and Dart SDK'
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: stable
          flutter-version: 3.3.9
          cache: true

      - name: 'Flutter enable Web'
        run: flutter config --enable-web

      - name: 'Get dependencies'
        run: flutter pub get
        working-directory: example/weathunits_configurator

      - name: 'Build web app'
        run: |
          cd example/weathunits_configurator
          flutter build web --web-renderer=canvaskit --base-href='/weathunits_configurator/' --release
      
      - name: 'Deploy web app'
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: example/weathunits_configurator/build/web
```

What I'm trying to do: my project lies in the `example/weathunits_configurator` folder, after building it will be in the `example/weathunits_configurator/build/web` folder.

The web project is placed in the `gh-pages` branch and looks like this [link](https://github.com/PackRuble/weather_animation/tree/gh-pages).
[image: Settings GitHub Pages in project]

We open the application through the https://packruble.github.io/weather_animation/ (I'd like to see another path. Not `/weather_animation/`, but `/weathunits_configurator/`.) and see a blank screen. I see the following in the console brave:
[image: in console brave]

**What I tried:**

1. Use `JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4` instead of `peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3`
2. Use different `flutter build web' parameters
3. Changed the input and output folder in settings deploy action.

I think the problem is that because my project, which needs to be deployed, is in a subfolder, it cannot be built normally. Either there is a problem with the `--base-href='/weathunits_configurator/'` tag. Or the problem is somewhere else.

**How to launch this project on Github Pages?**

Comment: Can you try with `--base-href /weathunits_configurator/`

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh, Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the problem was solved by using the `--base-href='/weather_animation/'` flag which specifies the repository name. It is the name of the github repository that should be specified in this flag and nothing else!

Recall that the file on the path `web/index.html` has the following line `<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">`.

And yes, sometimes github pages are not lightning fast. You need to wait some time for the changes to take effect after your deploy.

Comment: `You need to wait some time for the changes to take effect after your deploy.` How much time are we talking about here?

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan, After a deploy to github pages

Comment: Well I got it working within 10 minutes...

Comment: Yes, and you will agree that it is not instantaneous. (¬_¬ ) Sometimes it takes even longer

Answer (score 0):

Consider the error message:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source 
“https://packruble.github.io/weathunits_configurator/flutter.js”.   
  weather_animation:40:1
```

That means a `base-href` set to `/weathunits_configurator/` cannot work because a project GitHub Page is based on the repository name.
Here, it is `weather_animation`, *not* `weathunits_configurator`.

The simplest option would be to *rename* the repository into `weathunits_configurator`, and remove the `base-href`, since a [project site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites) is hosted at `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<repository>`.

That seems easier than [configuring a custom domain for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site).

---

The [OP Ruble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17991131/ruble) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74597644/unable-to-deploy-flutter-project-to-github-pages/75030398#comment132435801_75030398) it is working, but keeping `--base-href='/weather_animation/'`, using the name of the repository though.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive response. If I use `--base-href='/weather_animation/'` it still doesn't work on github, but if I copy all the files from the `gh-pages` branch and run it locally, it works fine. I understand that it is important that the project itself has the same name as the repository?

Comment: It worked with the `--base-href='/weather_animation/'` flag after some time waiting. Thank you again for your reply.